# Disable the `tabbar-mode` globally and erase everything related to it, in particular - the key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, tabbar

I'd like `tabbar-mode` to be forbidden in my Emacs setup; in particular, I'd like all the related `C-x t`-prefixed bindings to be erased. Is that possible in a plain vanilla Emacs of the latest stable version?

Comment: I think this question (wrt key bindings, which the accepted answer addresses) is a duplicate. I'm pretty sure it's been asked & answered many times: how to unbind a key binding, including a prefix key.

Comment: I thought that was just one aspect of the OP's question, so I suggested `unload-feature` in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can disable all those keybindings:

Emacs 29: `(keymap-set global-map "C-x t" nil)`

Earlier versions of emacs: `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x t") nil)`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way, I think, is to unload the feature and clean up the keymaps:

```
(tab-bar-mode -1)
(keymap-set ctl-x-map "t" nil)
(setq tab-prefix-map nil)
(makunbound 'tab-prefix-map)
(unload-feature 'tab-bar)
```

The first line makes sure that the mode is disabled, the second one deletes the tab prefix map from the `C-x t` key (so it is no longer a prefix key), the third one gets rid of the prefix map value so that it will be garbage-collected (this may not be necessary, given the next step), the fourth one "unbinds" the symbol and deletes it from the obarray. The last one unloads the feature.

I believe that's enough, although there may be other variables from `tab-bar.el` still in Emacs's memory (`unload-feature` does not clean up everything). You can use `makunbound/fmakunbound` on them if you really want to get rid of them, but unless you evaluate them or call them explicitly, they are just going to be moribund bystanders.

If you really want to eradicate every trace of `tab-bar-mode` from your Emacs, then you can build your own Emacs and get rid of `tab-bar.el` from the Makefile.

Comment: Good answer, not only works for `tab-bar.el`.